# Convert csv to dict in Apache Beam without knowing header fieldnames

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, python-3.8

Given an input CSV (stored locally or in Google Cloud Storage) of

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

How can I get a PCollection with value

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
{a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}
```

without knowing the name of the CSV headers in advance?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the standard csv.DictReader (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)?

Comment: I think the goal here is to read this as an input to Beam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options here.

(1) You can use `beam.io.ReadFromText` skipping the header, followed by `beam.Map(lambda line: zip(header_names, line.split(','))`. This won't handle quoting, etc. (though could be adapted to do so, possibly using the csv module, though handling multi-line rows won'w work with this method).

(2) You can use the Beam [dataframes API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) to do this, e.g.

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv

with beam.Pipeline as p:
    df = p | beam.dataframe.io.read_csv("/path/to/filepattern")
    # Here you can use df as if it were a Pandas dataframe,
    # or you can convert it into a PCollection of dicts with
    # pcoll = beam.dataframe.convert.to_pcollection(df)
```